# HTML: Turn Element invisible when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have a checkbox in the header of my html code and a box in the body. I need the box to disappear when the checkbox is checked.

I will provide the code below but in short I can make the checkbox itself disappear when it is checked but when I add in the class of the element I want to vanish it stops working at all. I have tried a couple different forms of the CSS but nothing has changed it.

```css
#toggle:checked ~ div .sidebar{
    display:none;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <label for="toggle" class="sidebar-toggle"></label>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="sidebar">
</div>
```

Comment: I would move the checkbox outside the nav to before the sidebar (I'm guessing it's hidden anyway and your label will still work).  If you do that, you can change the sibling selector to be an adjacent sibling selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a small typo in your CSS selector `#toggle:checked ~ div .sidebar`. There should be no space between `div` and `.sidebar` because your goal is to select "the `div` with class name `sidebar`" (not "any element with class name `sidebar` that is a child of a `div`").

Another issue is that you are incorrectly using the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) in your CSS selector. In order for your selector to work properly, the `div.sidebar` should be a child of the same parent as the `#toggle` element.

```css
#toggle:checked ~ div.sidebar {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <label for="toggle" class="sidebar-toggle"></label>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Was able to get this working. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you cannot change your HTML structure, since you are trying to alter a "div" that is not a sibling or a descendent of the checkbox, you will need javascript to do this.

```js
function handleChange(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked == true) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0].classList.add("hidden");;
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0].classList.remove("hidden");;
  }
}
```

```css
.sidebar.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <label for="toggle" class="sidebar-toggle"></label>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" onchange='handleChange(this)' />
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="sidebar">
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to get the CSS and HTML only answer working but I'm upvoting this as well because if my HTML were set in stone I would have needed this answer.